# Unable to establish connection to SQL Database from Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Currently I'm trying to make a simple website that allows a user to register a new account and login. Right now I'm trying connect the database to my application and keep getting this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrQyP.jpg `(A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server)`.

I've been googling around pretty much for the past 2 days and I'm at the end of my tether here. Just wondering if anybody would have any idea what I should do?

Comment: Wherever you are connecting from cannot see the database. It's in the cut-off portion of the error. There are about 50 million potential causes for this.

Comment: @mark, can you share the connection string ?

Comment: The error says "server not found " . Just check whether the sql server agent of the sql server machine is "on" or try restarting the sql server agent in : run>>services.msc>>your sql server agent>> right click and restart.

Comment: Consider this - a question title is your opportunity to "sell" your question to would-be-answerers. "Having an issue with..." is true for just about anyone posting a question to Stack Overflow. "an SQL database" is a detail best converyed in the question *tags* (And note that the [tag:sql] tag already tells you that you should also add a specific tag for your database system)

Comment: Run SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SSQL Server.  The login window will give you the server name and instance of the server.  Use same instance in your connection string.  the instance names varies with version of SQL Server that you are using and the issue is probably the instnace name in the connection string is wrong.

Comment: Like @JohnHC says, this could be a million reasons (firewall, incorrect connection string, SQL not setup to talk over TCP/IP).  What version of SQL are you attempting to connect to (Local, Express, Standard)?  Is it localhost or a network server? Your connection string (scrubbed of passwords) would be helpful to see.